# Dovecot-core fails to start

Tags: ubuntu, postfix, email-server, dovecot, ubuntu-14.04

I am attempting to follow this tutorial:

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-a-mail-server-using-postfix-dovecot-mysql-and-spamassassin

I believe someone before me attempted to set this all up on this box, but failed halfway through. I get stuck on the first command:

```
sudo apt-get install postfix postfix-mysql dovecot-core dovecot-imapd dovecot-lmtpd dovecot-mysql
```

This results in:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
dovecot-core is already the newest version.
dovecot-imapd is already the newest version.
postfix is already the newest version.
postfix-mysql is already the newest version.
dovecot-lmtpd is already the newest version.
dovecot-mysql is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 34 not upgraded.
4 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Setting up dovecot-core (1:2.2.9-1ubuntu5) ...
Creating generic self-signed certificate: /etc/dovecot/dovecot.pem
This certificate will expire in 10 years.
(replace with hand-crafted or authorized one if needed).
Job for dovecot.service failed. See "systemctl status dovecot.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
invoke-rc.d: initscript dovecot, action "start" failed.
dpkg: error processing package dovecot-core (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of dovecot-lmtpd:
 dovecot-lmtpd depends on dovecot-core (= 1:2.2.9-1ubuntu5); however:
  Package dovecot-core is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package dovecot-lmtpd (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of dovecot-imapd:
 dovecot-imapd depends on dovecot-core (= 1:2.2.9-1ubuntu5); however:
  Package dovecot-core is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package dovecot-imapd (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of dovecot-mysql:
 dovecot-mysql depends on dovecot-core (= 1:2.2.9-1ubuntu5); however:
  Package dovecot-core is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package dovecot-mysql (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 dovecot-core
 dovecot-lmtpd
 dovecot-imapd
 dovecot-mysql
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Appears that dovecot-core isn't properly starting... so I ran:

```
systemctl status dovecot.service
journalctl -xe
```

With the results of:

```
● dovecot.service - LSB: Dovecot init script


  Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/dovecot)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2015-07-15 13:43:31 EDT; 1min 59s ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  Process: 24790 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/dovecot start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
```

and

```
Jul 15 13:43:47 postfix[24814]: error: to submit mail, use the Postfix sendmail command
Jul 15 13:43:47 postfix[24814]: fatal: the postfix command is reserved for the superuser
```

I am now stuck and don't know what to do for the next step. Any advice would be appreciated...

EDIT: I have no problem starting over. If there's a way to nuke these installs completely and start fresh I'm happy to do so if that's easier than fixing this.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed by just running sudo apt-get purge dovecot-core